# Breaking an array items into certain number of rows

Tags: reactjs

```
renderItems() {
    const {items} = this.state;
    const results = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      results.push(
        <tr>
          {
            for (let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {

            }
          }
        </tr>
      )
    }
  }
```

Basically, I have an array of 32 items and would like to break it into 8 items per row (overall will be 4 rows), but the above code gives error for the inner loop inside `<tr>` which is correct (and im not sure how to correct it).

What would be the correct way in React to dynamically create 4 rows and put 8 `td`s inside each row?

Comment: Think about how to chunk your array into array of arrays first...then think about rendering that

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a for loop directly inside the `{}` in JSX since it expects an expression.

You could do the for loop outside of the JSX, or chunk the items array into arrays of length 8 and `map` over those.

**Example**

```
renderItems() {
  const items = [...this.state.items];
  const chunks = [];

  while (items.length) {
    chunks.push(items.splice(0, 8));
  }

  return chunks.map(chunk => (
    <tr>{chunk.map(item => <td>{item}</td>)}</tr>
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means an elegant solution, but it works:

```
renderItems() {
    const { items } = this.state;

    // first, create all the <td> elements and store them in a list
    let allTDs = []

    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        allTDs.push(<td key={ items[i] }> { items[i] } </td>)
    }

    //then break the list into four rows and keep them in separate lists
    let tr1 = [];
    let tr2 = [];
    let tr3 = [];
    let tr4 = [];

    // keep count for each row
    let count = 0

    for (let td of allTDs) {
      //first eight goes to the first row, second eight to the second etc.
      if(count < 8) {
        tr1.push(td)
      } else if (count < 16) {
        tr2.push(td)
      } else if (count < 24) {
        tr3.push(td)
      } else if (count < 32) {
        tr4.push(td)
      }
      count += 1;
    }

    // bring all four rows together in a list so that you can return that list
    let allTRs = [];
    allTRs.push(tr1, tr2, tr3, tr4)

    return allTRs
  }


 render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <tbody>

            // serve each row by calling the renderItems() method and indexing
            // the relevant row
            <tr>{ this.renderItems()[0] }</tr> 
            <tr>{ this.renderItems()[1] }</tr>
            <tr>{ this.renderItems()[2] }</tr>
            <tr>{ this.renderItems()[3] }</tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
```